# Angular Material with Angular 6 - Mat Menu drop down position issues

Tags: css, html, angular-material2

If you scroll down or open the developer tool(F12) after opened the mat menu the  position of the menu has been changed. I need to place the menu in the same place when we are scroll down or press F12. Please find the screenshot and link for your reference. 
[image]

Please find the sample code link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ntb2i

Comment: your stackblitz is not working.

Comment: @TimMartens please check the code now

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Resizing the screen causes the gives the menu item a slider, but I don't see any position changes

Comment: Assume that the mat menu has placed into center of the view port that time if press/open developer tool. the menu dropdwon will be moved into top of the viewport @TimMartens

Comment: @Mathi Did you find any resolution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to relocate the menu options. 
You can use this css margin code. Depends on the position you want to display add or sustract px to this code.

```
transformMenu.ng-tns-c111-0.ng-star-inserted.mat-elevation-z2.mat-menu-after.mat-menu-below {
margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;}
```

The css tags are from your stackblitz.